# What are all of the stage changes in Mega Man X?

Tags: mega-man-x

What are all the stage changes in Mega Man X (example: after defeating Storm Eagle, Spark Mandrill's stage is damaged, has intermittent blackouts, and the mini-boss can't charge his lightning attack), and what causes them?

I'm aware of 3 (freezing Flame Mammoth's stage, flooding Sting Chameleon's, and the aforementioned Spark Mandrill change) - are there more?

Comment: I believe those are all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately that's all the stage changes through boss killing.
Destroying the battle ship in Launch octopus's stage does open up another path (which changes the stage in a way, but not the same as the other three you mentioned).

Answer (score 4):

I doubt this counts, but if you beat the green mini boss of Sting Chameleons stage that gives you the body upgrade: the avalanche in the cave(still in Sting Chameleons stage) doesn't happen.